# Cosmos DB: Gremlin API Request too large exception. How to retry the call

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a Throughput of 1000 RU/s in my Azure Cosmos DB and I have around 290 queries to be executed. I keep getting request too large exception.

Each query have 12 properties and 1 Partition key but I still think with 1000 RU/s the queries should be executed properly.

I have a gremlinClient

```
    public static GremlinClient GetGremlinClient()
    {
        var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer(Endpoint, Port, enableSsl: true,
            username: "/dbs/" + Databasename + "/colls/" + Collectionname, password: Authkey);
        var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(gremlinServer, new GraphSON2Reader(), new GraphSON2Writer(),
            GremlinClient.GraphSON2MimeType);
        return gremlinClient;
    }
```

A sample query. I am just trying to add vertices

> g.addV('Experience').property('_test', 'dummy').property('someProperty', 'dummy').property('someProperty', 'dummy').property('someProperty', 'Documentation of the business processes
>   of all departments as well as the management level for an informed
>   selection of an ERP-system for a medium-sized industrial enterprise;
>   Role: Project management ').property('someProperty',
>   '2016').property('someProperty', 'Offen').property('someProperty',
>   'Dummy').property('someProperty', 'EN').property('someProperty',
>   'Industry').property('someProperty', 'Process documentation of
>   the whole company for a profounded selection of an ERP-System.')

That for-each executes all the queries

```
  foreach (string query in queries)
  {
            await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(query);
  }
```

The error I get

> Server error: \r\n\nActivityId : 2312f64f-b865-49cc-bb26-843d46313199\nExceptionType : RequestRateTooLargeException\nExceptionMessage :\r\n\tMessage: {\"Errors\":[\"Request rate is large\"]}\r\n\tActivityId: 157daf87-3238-4e1c-9a81-41bcd6d7c2e1, Request URI: /apps/413f848b-ce17-40fc-ad7f-14c0e21e9633/services/29abd22a-4e74-48c1-aab3-b311be968829/partitions/9e4cb405-4f74-4d7f-8d12-26e79b910143/replicas/132142016542682221s/, RequestStats: \r\n\tRequestStartTime: 2019-10-24T09:27:38.2395067Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-10-24T09:27:38.2395067Z, Number of regions attempted:1\r\n\tResponseTime: 2019-10-24T09:27:38.2395067Z

Its a simple code I dont understand what I can change in that.

Is there a way to retry the request for the same point or somehow not get the error or to avoid the error

Comment: So... you're just submitting a batch of a few hundred queries at the same time? You haven't shown the queries, nor the per-query cost, so as written it's difficult to guess, but... assuming you blasted all of these queries at the same time (like, within the same one-second window), then each query would need to cost, on average, 29 RU. Otherwise you'd get throttled (which I'm assuming is what you mean by "request too large"). And depending on which direction you navigate your edges, queries could be much more expensive. Please consider editing your question with more detail.

Comment: All the queries are in queries list and I am trying to execute each one individually in Foreach loop. at least thats my assumption that with for each it will submit one query at a time

Comment: is this a wrong approach of submitting the queries?

Comment: I followed MS Sample and they were also using it in a similar way https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-gremlindotnet-getting-started/blob/master/GremlinNetSample/Program.cs

Comment: But what is in the other queries? You can print each query before submitting, so you know which one is causing the exception. Also, adding the exact error you get to the question might help.

Comment: all the queries are similar to the one 1 mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you receive is `Request*Rate*TooLargeException`, meaning you are submitting too many request in a short period of time.

For running bulk operations you should use the [vendor specific tooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-graph-dotnet).